# Definition of semi-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following two definitions of semi-continuous function:

1. [Notes from Washington University](https://pages.wustl.edu/files/pages/imce/nachbar/semi-continuity.pdf)
2. [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity)

It is clear that we need the definition of contour in order to define the semi-continuous function. My question is:

It is not clear to me which space do we require to define it?

Wiki uses topological space to define it. Whereas, the other note mentions metric space. Loosely, all the metric spaces are topological spaces [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621595/is-topological-space-a-metric-space), but I need a concrete definition.

Comment: First part of the first sentence in the Wikipedia article you linked to: *In mathematical analysis, semi-continuity (or semicontinuity) is a property of extended real-valued functions ...* This says that for semicontinuous functions, the function must output extended real numbers, while nothing is said about the domain (i.e. space the inputs belong to) of the function. Wikipedia defines this for domains that are topological spaces and the notes you linked to defines this for the more special case in which domains are metric spaces.

Comment: Incidentally, [one can define semicontinuous functions in more general settings than those in Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semi-continuous+function%22+%22generalized+topological%22) (e.g. see for example [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10474-019-01013-5)), but such generalities are of much less interest (at least at the present time) and I imagine the Wikipedia writers had to establish a limit somewhere as to how far down the rabbit hole to go regarding each mathematical topic.